# how to take numbers from string and store in an array?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = 'asdf234awe324wese34'; // or string -> '23asdre34ere' or something
```

numbers should be in an array like this:

```
var strArr = [234,324,34]; // if string or -> [23,34] or something
```

> might be answer?

```
var a = '23wer234sdf45';
var reg = /\d+/g;
var store = a.match(reg);
//alert(store[2]);//alerts 45
```

But now how can I store it in an array?

```
var storeArray = []; //insert matched numbers here
```

So that I could use it by calling apply() method later in my project....

> no such project, just to learning for fun

Comment: storeArray is ALREADY an array with all your matches. No need to do anything more!

Comment: match() already returns an array

Comment: you want to clone the array or something?

Comment: @sfletche you mean I can call like this: apply(this,store) ???

Comment: no, i mean you can simply say `var storeArray = store;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = '23wer234sdf45';
var reg = /\d+/g;
var store = a.match(reg);
console.log(store[0]);
console.log(store[1]);
console.log(store[2]);
```

Like everyone else said it's already an array, but in case not then:

```
var storeArray = [store[0], store[1], store[2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substring method`.

```
int str = 'asdf234awe324wese34';
var storeArray = [];
storeArray[0] = str.subString(4,7);
storeArray[1] = str.subString(10,13);
storeArray[2] = str.subString(17,19);
```